# Is there a list of well used values for the "generator" meta tag?

Tags: html

Some sites, such as blogs running WordPress provide a meta tag called "generator".

For example, on my WordPress blog, when I view the source code the following meta tag is added:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.9.1" />
```

I am wondering if someone has created a list of the most commonly used generator tags?

Comment: What do you intend to do with the information? Such tags are basically write-only – not used by browsers or seach engines, though people reading HTML source might be interested in seeing what software produced the mess.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I am just trying to create some analysis for the type of content that is usually generated by different applications, and wanted to see if I could get a list of commonly used generators to check my data against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, after changing my search queries to use different words for "meta generator" (which was giving me sites for copy & paste snippets for the HTML `<head>` tag) I now have found two sites with a list of meta tags, which is what I was looking for:

- http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2012/q1/att-132/meta-generator-tags.txt
- http://pagerankings.com/wordpress-number-website-site-generator/